# Visual Basic MDI application modal sub-dialogs

Tags: forms, vb6, modal-dialog, mdi, mdichild

I have a very complex application, written in Visual Basic 6.
The main dialog of this application is an MDI form.

My problem is:
There are a lot of dialogs (e.G. message boxes), these have to be modal. But modal dialogs cannot stay inside the frame of the MDI main form.

My question is:
How could this problem be solved? The (standard VB) message boxes and other (custom) modal dialogs should not be allowed to be moved outside of the MDI dialog's frame.

Comment: Why is it necessary to keep the dialogs within the bounds of the main form?

Comment: This is the requirement of the software, thats why :)

Comment: :) I get that, but sometimes when a "requirement" contradicts something fundamental in the technology it is worth pushing back on it or at least making sure it is really solving the right problem. We sometimes have customers who will say they want X but really when we dig into it what they ask for is only their idea of a solution and not the underlying issue. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: DaveInCaz, please correct me if I understood You clearly... :)
So... the VB6 does not support this, what I would like to do, right?

The users wanted this, because the non-modal dialogs of an MDI app can "go away" (means: the user clicks everywhere else, and then the windows seems to be "disappeared"; but in the reality it went only in the background (since other windows came in foreground).

But if we use simply modal dialogs, then the users "dont find them anymore", but the whole applications is "blocked" (until the dialog window is not clicked away).

Any idea? :)

Comment: I didn't mean that I am 100% certain that it can't be done - there are often useful Windows API tricks, for instance, when VB6 doesn't directly support something. I think this is a valid technical question.